# Why do successive elements with negative margins influence the content flow differently than a single element with negative margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

Screenshot of Result of code-example below:
[image]

I have 3 columns of items in the example:

- The first column contains 4 boxes with normal content flow.
- The second column contains the same boxes but one box has the class `.negative` which
  enlarges the element with negative margin and padding. **Notice the
  column has the same height as the first one**.
- The third column contains 2 successive elements with the same `.negative` class. **Notice the content flow below changed and the column now has a different height!**

#### How can i avoid this change in content flow, to have a .negative class without affecting other elements and what causes this?

Code Example:

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


.negative {
  position: relative;
  margin: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > * {
  width: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for the `.negative` class using relative positioning, but i dont know what causes the problem with successive elements.

Important to know is that not all margins work the same way, so we are using 2 directions with margins and 2 directions with relative positions here.

```css
.box {
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


.negative {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container > * {
  width: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box negative"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```